# Data to be sent in payload via APNS

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I am using APNS in my app and i wanted to send some data ( ofcourse less than 256 bytes ). My problem is that I wants to send the data with Push notification without showing any alert to the user. How can i do that ?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Specify badge in aps key, and put your data in some other key. So if you're using badge numbers, recalculate the correct badge number, if you're not using them, just send 0.

From Apple docs:

> Providers can specify custom payload values outside the Apple-reserved aps namespace. Custom values must use the JSON
>   structured and primitive types: dictionary (object), array, string,
>   number, and Boolean. You should not include customer information as
>   custom payload data. Instead, use it for such purposes as setting
>   context (for the user interface) or internal metrics. For example, a
>   custom payload value might be a conversation identifier for use by an
>   instant-message client application or a timestamp identifying when the
>   provider sent the notification. Any action associated with an alert
>   message should not be destructive—for example, deleting data on the
>   device.

But there is a catch - this will only work if app is running.

The way it works is - 
If app is running, you get a notification via didReceiveRemoteNotification callback with the payload data. You can extract your custom data here. 
However if app is not running, normally an alert is displayed and your app is notified *only* if user taps on it. Since you don't want to display an alert - there is *no way* for you to get custom payload data when app is not running. When you think about it, it'll be pretty scary for the user if apps started up on their own. :)

Comment: `if ([launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]) { Do some thing on Push notification // }`   Whenever I am using alert key in JSON structure, then this code in `DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` runs on Notification tap but as mentioned in question, i doesn't want to display alert for notification. What should i do ?

Comment: If i dont specify `alert` key in JSON structure, then the `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey` returns null.

Comment: ok..now i have created `alert` key as empty.And included `badge` key. Badge is showing on push notification occurrence but when i run the app by tapping on app icon which is displaying badge=1, `[launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]` is still null. Why it is so ?

Comment: @hawkeye_01 Tapping the app icon will never deliver the notification data to your app, even if you did dispay an alert (in which case the data is available to the app only if the user open the app from the alert). You should contact your server when the app starts and get all the data you need from there.